# @PreDestroy on Session-scoped Spring MVC Controllers

Tags: spring-mvc

Given a `@RestController` like so:

```
@RestController
@Scope("session")
public class MyController {
    @PreDestroy
    public void onSessionDestroyed() {
        // clean stuff up...
    }
}
```

Would `onSessionDestroyed()` be called when the session expires?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, your `@PreDestroy` annotated method will be called on session expiry. The only scope where @PreDestroy annotated method is not called is for Prototype scope.

**Edit**: Adding a little more detail on how this works -

The session scope is handled by a `SessionScope` class which has a  `registerDestructionCallback` method internally. Now this callback gets triggered through a `DestructionCallbackBindingListener` which is a [HttpSessionBindingListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) which listens for session expiry and triggers the call to `@PostDestroy` method of the relevant scoped beans.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, yes, Spring will call `@PreDestroy`. It will not work for Prototype scoped beans, but it does for Session scoped beans. Spring continues to respect the lifecycle of Session scoped beans.