# Spring MVC @PreDestroy method not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using @controller in my controller class which internally creates bean. For this controller I need to use @postConstruct and @preDestroy methods, @postConstruct is working fine but @preDestroy is not working. It means Bean is not destroying. So how can I destroy bean in spring MVC(annotation based)(I am not using ApplicationContext).
Correct me if my assumption was wrong.

Comment: When do you expect your `@PreDestroy` method to be invoked ? What is the scope of that bean ? Separately, when you say you're "not using `ApplicationContext`", I guess you just mean that you didn't define a root application context in `web.xml` -- as it's pretty hardcore to make use of Spring MVC with no application context.

Comment: You must use close function to work the @preDestroy method.

Comment: Before destroying bean  i need to invoke @preDestroy method. Without using ApplicationContext we cannot destroy a bean?

Comment: hi pavan, you meant by not using application context that u are using annotation configuration right? u still have a context..just not creating it via xml config...pls correct me if i misunderstood u.

Answer (score 0):

WHen you say you dont use application context, do you mean to say that you are not using xml based configuration and are using java annotation config?

With spring mvc controllers, @PreDestroy annotated method will be called on session expiry (unless it's prototype scoped)

Here is a post [@PreDestroy on Session-scoped Spring MVC Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22848563/predestroy-on-session-scoped-spring-mvc-controllers)

Here is a good explantation  on spring bean life cycle http://www.journaldev.com/2637/spring-bean-life-cycle-methods-initializingbean-disposablebean-postconstruct-predestroy-aware-interfaces

Answer (score 0):

I found out that if I set the bean scope to singleton, I can get PreDestroy called but not if I set it to prototype.